# Is there an enchanted item duplication bug in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I enchanted a bow with Power 1, and now I have three bows all with Power 1 on them. Did monsters drop the others, or is there an item duplication bug in Minecraft?

Comment: Good question. I've seen them drop bows (And an iron helmet so far) but nothing enchanted.

Answer (score 11):

Skeletons have the chance to drop both enchanted and unenchanted bows. It sounds like you've been pretty lucky with your anti-skeleton tactics!

Comment: I was very lucky, in that there is a skeleton spawn box right outside my castle's basement, and I have about 30 dogs parked in it.

Comment: I have had a Zombie Pigman drop an enchanted golden sword. You're not seeing a dupe bug, you're getting blessed by the RNG.